# ReactJS server-side rendering issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Please help me to understand my issue.

I have the following on the **server**-side (Node.js):

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');

var TestComponent = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return <div>test</div>
  }
});

// express router callback..
function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(TestComponent));
};
```

An example of **response**:

```
<div data-reactid=".2e2hyaaz0n4" data-react-сhecksum="1124798100">test</div>
```

And on the **client**-side:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(template), document.getElementById('container'));
```

I'm having the following **error** in browser console:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid tag: <div data-reactid=".2e2hyaaz0n4" data-react-checksum="1124798100">test</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `template` contains the string

```js
'<div data-reactid=".2e2hyaaz0n4" data-react-сhecksum="1124798100">test</div>'
```

then this is not quite correct. You can never render plain HTML as if it were JSX. Instead you should include the server-rendered HTML as part of the page source when it is rendered, and then initialize the client-side React application using the **same props** as used on the server.

So, for example, using the EJS template engine:

```js
// In Express

function(req, res, next) {
  var reactHtml = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<TestComponent />);
  res.render('index.ejs', {reactOutput: reactHtml});
};
```

```html
<!-- In a template somewhere -->
<div id="container"><%- reactOutput %></div>
```

```js
// In a client-side JavaScript file

var TestComponent = React.createClass({
  render : function() {
    return <div>test</div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

See [How to Implement Node + React Isomorphic JavaScript & Why it Matters](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-react-isomorphic-javascript-why-it-matters/) for more information.

Comment: Please check that https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring Looks like it should be possible..

Comment: @OlegMeleshko Can you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean by your comment.

Comment: If you call ReactDOM.render() on a node that already has this server-rendered markup, React will preserve it and only attach event handlers, allowing you to have a very performant first-load experience.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko That is correct. To do that, you would use the strategy outlined here — output the server-rendered markup *as part of the HTML template*, then call `render` on the node that already contains the markup *using the same input JSX*. You *cannot* fetch the HTML from the page and call `render` on that.

Comment: I'm getting my html via ajax, so do you mean I could wrap it up somehow and then render as a React component?

Comment: @OlegMeleshko I'm not sure I understand — why render it on the server if you're fetching it via Ajax? You get no benefit from this. Just run the React code on the client. To answer your question, you **cannot run or use HTML as a React component**, you can *only* render actual React components.

Comment: I don't want to do compile ops on client side (except attaching events as mentioned in docs). I want to keep and render html on server side (react server-side rendering).

Comment: @OlegMeleshko You cannot attach events without running the JavaScript on the client as well. To say another way, it is not *enough* to only use server rendering; you must also use client rendering (if you want event handling)

Comment: Correct, and I do, but I don't want to keep jsx on client side. I want to manipulate and render (attach events) already precompiled html (from the server)

Comment: @OlegMeleshko You cannot. You *must* execute the React code (e.g., with JSX) client side. There is no way for the server HTML to contain all the code necessary to make the eventing work.

Comment: but `React.createElement` creates an Element without errors and at this point everything works well.

Comment: @OlegMeleshko `React.createElement` does not do any error checking. What you are attempting to render is not a valid React element.

Comment: If so, I will be really disappointed about that. I will do some research around that a bit more and if no results, will give you best answer check mark. Thank you!

Comment: And what about supplying the initialState without waiting for a ajax call after the React component has been loaded in the browser? How to supply this data to the client, for making sure the client and server versions will have the same props? If in a script tag in the template how to parse it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you send just a `div` tag without a real document. This means that on the server you should write something like this:

```
function(req, res, next) {
  const component = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(TestComponent);

  const layout = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head lang="en">
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <title>Isomorphic app</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">${component}</div>
      </body>
    </html>`;

  res.send(layout);
};
```

Also you can check out [this repo](https://github.com/ivantsov/isomorphic-app-sample/tree/master/server) with an example of simple isomorphic app.

Comment: Nope, it's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mount the component on the element having id **container**.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(template), document.getElementById('container'));
```

But you missed to add the element with id **container** in the component rendered from serverside. 
 To achieve this use a template like *Jade*.

```
div(class="container")
```

renderedHTMLString

If u want to replace entire body just add this client side.

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(template), document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```